# How to write an odata filter in a logic app where field has date time and I just want to use date portion

Tags: salesforce, odata, azure-logic-apps

There is a record in the Salesforce Stay Information which has the following information. "Booked_Check_in_Date_Time__c": "2022-11-05T00:59:00Z"

When I try the following oData filter it does not work.
Booked_Check_in_Date_Time__c eq 2022-11-05

What do I need to change to bring back this record.

Comment: Can you use  `date(Booked_Check_in_Date_Time__c) eq 2022-11-05` to compare just the date disregarding the time?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not using the complete query to filter the results.

> What do I need to change to bring back this record.

In your case you need to use the below query format to get the filtered results.

```
Booked_Check_in_Date_Time__c eq `2022-11-05T00:59:00Z`
```

*RESULTS:*

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looked like I needed to use Local_Booked_Checkin_Date__c to achieve what I needed.  If I used Booked_Check_in_Date_Time__c I would have to add time to the filter which I did not want to.